# Creating python thread from within function causing error

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a thread within a function and am recieving an error

Here is my code:

```
from threading import Thread

def threadFunction(parameter):
    print(parameter)

def main():
        parameter = "abc"
        t = Thread(target='threadFunction', args=(parameter, ))
        t.start()
        t.join()

main()
```

And am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 t = Thread(target=threadFunction, args=(parameter, ))
```

No quotes. Pass the function value itself, not a string that happens to be spelled the same as when you defined it in source code.